# Convert Spark DataFrame to HashMap

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hashmap, tuples, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
product1 product2 difference
123      456      0.5
123      789      1
456      789      0
456      123      0.5
789      123      1
789      456      0
```

I would like an output that looks like this:

```
{'123': {'456': 0.5, '789': 1}, 456: {'123': 0.5, '789': 1}, '789': {'123': 1, '456': 0}}
```

so far I have tried `zipWithIndex` and `collectAsMap` with no luck.

The code I have tried so far is:

```
val tples: RDD[(Int, (Int, Double))] = (products.rdd
  .map(r => (r(0).toString.toDouble.toInt, (r(1).toString.toDouble.toInt, r(2).toString.toDouble))))
val lst: = tpls.groupByKey().map(r => (r._1, r._2.toSeq))
```

This gives me a list of products and differences instead of a hash map

Comment: I believe you still have an RDD, not a list... If you wanted a Hashmap , you must collect the RDD

Comment: Is this a typo? `456 -> 789 -> 1` should be `456 -> 789 -> 0.0` in the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first convert the dataframe to a RDD, transform it to key-value type, and perform a `groupByKey`.  To obtain the result in the wanted `Map` form, you'll need to `collect` the grouped RDD (thus may not be doable for large dataset):

```
val df = Seq(
  (123, 456, 0.5),
  (123, 789, 1.0),
  (456, 789, 0.0),
  (456, 123, 0.5),
  (789, 123, 1.0),
  (789, 456, 0.0)
).toDF("product1", "product2", "difference")

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val groupedRDD = df.rdd.map{
    case Row(p1: Int, p2: Int, diff: Double) => (p1, (p2, diff))
  }.
  groupByKey.mapValues(_.toMap)

groupedRDD.collectAsMap
// res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Any,scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Double]] = Map(
//   456 -> Map(789 -> 0.0, 123 -> 0.5), 789 -> Map(123 -> 1.0, 456 -> 0.0), 123 -> Map(456 -> 0.5, 789 -> 1.0)
// )
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want something like this:

```
val myRdd = sc.makeRDD(List(
  (123, (456, 0.5)), 
  (123, (789, 1.0)), 
  (456, (789, 0.0)), 
  (456, (123, 0.5)), 
  (789, (123, 1.0)), 
  (789, (456, 0.0))
))


val myHashMap = myRdd.groupByKey.mapValues(_.toMap).collect.toMap

// gives:
// scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Double]] = 
//   Map(
//     456 -> Map(789 -> 0.0, 123 -> 0.5), 
//     789 -> Map(123 -> 1.0, 456 -> 0.0), 
//     123 -> Map(456 -> 0.5, 789 -> 1.0)
//   )
```

Brief explanation: `groupByKey` gives you tuples like `(123, Seq((456, 0.5), (789, 1.0)))`. You want to convert the second component (the "values") to a map, so you call `mapValues(_.toMap)`. Then (if you really want to load the collection to your node and convert it to local, non-distributed map), you must call `collect`. This gives you essentially a list of tuples of type `(Int, Map[Int, Double])`. Now you can call `toMap` on this collection to obtain a map of maps.